# Query works on a table with a subset of a larger table, but does not work on the larger table

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a large Transactions table.  I copied all of the transactions for a specific item to another table (called TransactionsTest) with the same exact columns for me to test on.

The Tranactions table looks like this:

```
+----------------+--------------+---------------------+-------------+----------------------+
| Transaction_ID | Inventory_ID |   Transaction_DT    | Location_ID | Transaction_Quantity |
+----------------+--------------+---------------------+-------------+----------------------+
|          39993 |          302 | 2017-01-26 12:41:00 |           1 |                    2 |
|          39964 |          112 | 2017-01-26 9:55:00  |          20 |                    1 |
|          39890 |          417 | 2017-01-20 9:54:00  |           3 |                    5 |
|          39794 |          302 | 2017-01-11 9:50:00  |           3 |                    3 |
|          39790 |          302 | 2017-01-10 10:45:00 |          20 |                    2 |
|          39681 |          225 | 2017-01-02 8:32:00  |          20 |                    4 |
|          39682 |          227 | 2017-01-02 8:15:00  |           1 |                    1 |
|          39679 |          302 | 2017-01-01 11:23:00 |           3 |                    6 |
|          39599 |          302 | 2016-12-11 10:21:00 |           1 |                    2 |
+----------------+--------------+---------------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

So the TransactionsTest table with only the transactions for a specific item looks like this:

```
+----------------+--------------+---------------------+-------------+----------------------+
| Transaction_ID | Inventory_ID |   Transaction_DT    | Location_ID | Transaction_Quantity |
+----------------+--------------+---------------------+-------------+----------------------+
|          39993 |          302 | 2017-01-26 12:41:00 |           1 |                    2 |
|          39794 |          302 | 2017-01-11 9:50:00  |           3 |                    3 |
|          39790 |          302 | 2017-01-10 10:45:00 |          20 |                    2 |
|          39679 |          302 | 2017-01-01 11:23:00 |           3 |                    6 |
|          39599 |          302 | 2016-12-11 10:21:00 |           1 |                    2 |
+----------------+--------------+---------------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

I built 2 different queries to return only the most recent transaction to each location. Here is the first:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM TransactionsTest t1
WHERE t1.Transaction_DT = (SELECT MAX(t2.Transaction_DT)
                           FROM TransactionsTest t2
                           WHERE t2.Location_ID = t1.Location_ID)
AND Inventory_ID = 302 ORDER BY t1.Transaction_DT
```

And here is the second:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM TransactionsTest t1
WHERE t1.Transaction_ID = (SELECT TOP 1 t2.Transaction_ID
                           FROM TransactionsTest t2
                           WHERE t2.Location_ID = t1.Location_ID
                           ORDER BY t2.Transaction_ID DESC)
AND Inventory_ID = 302 ORDER BY t1.Transaction_DT
```

Both queries return this result when querying TransactionsTest:

```
+----------------+--------------+---------------------+-------------+----------------------+
| Transaction_ID | Inventory_ID |   Transaction_DT    | Location_ID | Transaction_Quantity |
+----------------+--------------+---------------------+-------------+----------------------+
|          39993 |          302 | 2017-01-26 12:41:00 |           1 |                    2 |
|          39794 |          302 | 2017-01-11 9:50:00  |           3 |                    3 |
|          39790 |          302 | 2017-01-10 10:45:00 |          20 |                    2 |
+----------------+--------------+---------------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

But when I run the same queries on the actual Transactions table, like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Transactions t1
WHERE t1.Transaction_DT = (SELECT MAX(t2.Transaction_DT)
                           FROM Transactions t2
                           WHERE t2.Location_ID = t1.Location_ID)
AND Inventory_ID = 302 ORDER BY t1.Transaction_DT
```

Or this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Transactions t1
WHERE t1.Transaction_ID = (SELECT TOP 1 t2.Transaction_ID
                           FROM Transactions t2
                           WHERE t2.Location_ID = t1.Location_ID
                           ORDER BY t2.Transaction_ID DESC)
AND Inventory_ID = 302 ORDER BY t1.Transaction_DT
```

The result set is empty like this:

```
+----------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+----------------------+
| Transaction_ID | Inventory_ID | Transaction_DT | Location_ID | Transaction_Quantity |
+----------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+----------------------+
|                |              |                |             |                      |
+----------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Can anyone tell what is going on here?  Why would the queries return the expected result only on the table with the transactions for a specific item?  The only thing I can think of is it might have something to do with how the original Transactions table was created because I did not duplicate all of the constraints/foreign keys, etc.

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL. What are you *really* using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inventory condition needs to be in the subquery as well:

```
WHERE t1.Transaction_ID = (SELECT TOP 1 t2.Transaction_ID
                           FROM TransactionsTest t2
                           WHERE t2.Location_ID = t1.Location_ID AND
                                 t2.Inventory_ID = t.Inventory_ID
                           ORDER BY t2.Transaction_ID DESC
                          )
```

Otherwise, the most recent transaction might have another value for `Inventory_ID`.

Comment: This worked! Adding

AND t2.Inventory_ID = t1.Inventory_ID

to both queries returned the expected result from the full Transactions table.